# Not sure how to convert SQL to Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I run this SQL statement

```
select * from checkins where user_id in (SELECT friend_id from friendships where user_id=1);
```

**Users Table**

id | name | email

**Friendships Table**

user_id | friend_id

**Checkins Table**

user_id | checkin_time

I've tried

```
friends = Friendship.select("friend_id").where("user_id = 1");
```

`Checkin.where("user_id = "+friends);`

Any ideas on how to rewrite this with Active Record? I feel like there should be a simple way to pull this out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Checkin.joins("INNER JOIN friendships ON friendships.friend_id = checkins.user_id).where('friendships.user_id = ?', 1)
```

or, for something more like your original idea:

```
friends = Friendship.select("friend_id").where("user_id = 1").map { |f| f.friend_id };
Checkin.where(:user_id => friends);
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem I'm having is that the .where clause does not act as a "where in", so it returns nothing. For example, I believe Checkin.where(:user_id => friends) is executing "SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE user_id = "2,3"; which isn't going to return anything.

Comment: if you user the hash syntax for where, rather than the array syntax you've used in your query where behaves differently. e.g. `Model.where(:attr => 1) # SELECT * FROM model WHERE attr = 1` vs `Model.where(:attr => [1,3,5]) # SELECT * FROM model WHERE attr IN (1,3,5)`. Take a look at the 'Hash conditions' section in the following guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Maybe in the second case it should be possible to use `pluck`[1], `Friendship.where(:user_id => 1).pluck(:friend_id)` should work.

[1]: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck